# how to update a text file without changing the contents

Tags: c, file, file-io

hi there i'm wondering that if is it possible to update a textfile which i mean add some text to all rows without changing the content. Suppose a textfile like this.

```
A
B
C
D
E
F
G
```

and i want to update like this way(adding another characters near to the first character off all rows)

```
A   H
B   I
C   J
D   K
E   L
F   M
G   N
```

when i open a textfile in append mode and use `fseek()` function in various ways even it can add some data in rows, some data from the end is going to missing everytime.

i hope its clear to understand the issue and i will appreciated if you can help. thanks anyway.

Comment: What's the code you've tried? And how did it screw up the output?

Comment: I don't think so you can. Probably, you will need keep this values into memory, organize as do you want, and so, write back into file by using w mode.

Comment: @Jack yeah it will work that way but it is more longer and unefficient i guess. on the other hand, i researched the web and most of comments agrees with your's.

Comment: @Mike i used   
`fseek ( pFile , 4 , SEEK_SET );
fprintf( pFile,"\tC");` to add 'C' character near to the first character of 4th row. actually it works but last row of textfile is missing after editing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The file model accessed through C and POSIX file operations presents files as a sequence of bytes, and there is no insert operation. You can only write over existing bytes (replacing them), add new bytes to the end, or truncate the file.

To create the output you desire, you must write to a new file. After you are done reading the input file, you could move the new file to the path of the old file, thus replacing the old file with the new output.

Comment: yeah i got it. new file is the only solution then. thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is to simply read in all the data into memory, and write the file out with the desired format. Sometimes it's better to sacrifice a bit of efficiency for readability and maintainability.

Comment: well there is nothing else to do except this way. by the way, thanks for reply.

Answer (score 0):

The concept of a 'row' in a text file really just means that you have a newline ('\n') character in the file.

To add data after the first element of a row in your text file, find the character you want to append after, then put your data between that character and the next newline character.

Comment: well i guess you misunderstood the issue. just think adding a second column or like the command "go to first row and skip the first character and print the second character." moreover, think this process to all rows

Comment: Is it possible to know which character is added to particular row? For eg:Is it possible to know **H** is added to the row containing **A**?

Comment: yeah actually i would print second columns' characters according to first rows' characters.

Comment: Then copy the content of the original file content, and perform insertion operation and write to the new output file, as the appropriate format. This may not the efficient method.